# Toroidal/cylinder single turn transformer to circular waveguide coupling

Tags: power, rf, power-electronics, radio, electromagnetic

[image]The questions is mostly in the title. Is it possible to effectively couple a toroidal/cylinder shaped ferrite core with thick spread out single turn of wire to a circular waveguide?
The idea is that the core would be mounted on the outside of the waveguide and the wire could enter the waveguide through an opening at one side.

The idea is to have power transfer from the outer toroid/cylinder core to the waveguide.

[image]

Comment: Please draw a diagram of your proposal.

Comment: I'm going to guess no, as there's no way a toroid *larger than* an (unloaded?) waveguide still has meaningful transformer action.  But a diagram is required (please include material types as well).

Comment: @Andy aka , I attached a simple drawing. Tim Williams well, the idea is that one has a toroid core in which RF magnetic flux is induced, this flux then needs to be transfered as RF power to a waveguide. So I have a multistrand flat litz wire , as an example, looped around the toroid and then looped into the RF waveguide to couple it. The "transformer action" should happen in theory in a normal way, where the toroid induced current in the single turn loop that then couples this to the RF field within the waveguide, should it not?

Comment: No it won't work.

Comment: And the waveguide wall is solid--? How would you expect fields within to couple with anything outside?

Comment: @Andy aka sorry my drawing isn't up to task, there is my mentioned single turn wire around the toroid which should in theory couple to the RF guide inside through an opening , or by the other methods RF fields are normally coupled to waveguides.

Comment: @Tim Williams I updated the drawing, i thought you would read my text and imagine the wire and coupling but I guess not so i added it to the drawing. I think in theory one can couple a outside magnetic field to a waveguide through a conductor of appropriate cross section, type and geometry?

Comment: I take drawings more seriously than text; we all struggle with descriptions from time to time, and some are better at imagining things than others.  It's not clear what you mean here, or why, so a drawing is key. So, what would the core be doing, that simply feeding the antenna/loop directly can't do?

Comment: there would be multiple cores, so the idea is to efficiently gather up the total energy produced within them and to couple it to a waveguide which can then guide that energy to wherever is needed.